# PHP RegEx - no ending delimiter?

Tags: php, regex

I am fairly new to RegEx and felt I somewhat got the hang of the basics when I was working with my .htaccess file.  I am currently working on some form validation to check that the user inputs a valid serial number to the system.  The system can accept the following serial format.

- I-SERIAL-123
- I-SERIAL123
- SERIAL-123
- SERIAL123

I am using the preg_match function to check whether this expression is satisfied, if so the field is submitted.

Current Expression

```
if (preg_match("^[A-Z0-9\-]{5}$", $_GET['serial']) === false)
```

However PHP keeps throwing an "No ending delimiter found" exception, I've looked at a couple of PHP cheat sheets and I don't see any immediate issues in my syntax.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're missing "/" at the beginning and the end of pattern

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need delimiters around your regex, usually `/`s:

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9\-]{5}$/", $_GET['serial']) === false)
                ^---------------^
```

But any non-alphanumeric character is valid (even paired brackets), although it makes most sense to use `~`, `#` or other symbols that aren't regex metacharacters or often used in text searches:

```
if (preg_match("#^[A-Z0-9\-]{5}$#", $_GET['serial']) === false)
```

In your case, as pointed out by Andy Lester, the regex engine thinks that `^` was supposed to be the delimiter (possible, but you then lose the "start of string" anchor for use in your regex and have to use `\A` instead):

```
if (preg_match("^\A[A-Z0-9\-]{5}$^", $_GET['serial']) === false)
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, I feel so silly to think that it was only just that.  I thought "/" represent that you are wanting to look for a trailing slash.

Thanks very much sir.

Comment: To be more clear, PHP is seeing the `^` in the original query as the delimiter, and since the string doesn't end with a `^`, you get the "No ending delimiter found".

Comment: Yes, the delimiter could be any non-alphanumeric symbol (such as `#` or `@`, for example)

Comment: [Regex cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)